# bash gnu parallel help

Tags: bash, loops, replace, parallel-processing, gnu

its about 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(software)
and very rich manpage http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

```
(for x in `cat list` ; do 
       do_something $x
   done) | process_output
```

is replaced by this

```
 cat list | parallel do_something | process_output
```

i am trying to implement that on this

```
    while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]
        do          
        percentage=${"scale=2;(100-(($n / $end) * 100))"|bc -l}}
    #get url from line specified by n from file done1              
nextUrls=`sed -n "${n}p" < done1`
    echo -ne "${percentage}%  $n / $end urls saved going to line 1. current: $nextUrls\r"
#    function that gets links from the url
    getlinks $nextUrls
#save n
    echo $n > currentLine
    let "n--"
    let "end=`cat done1 |wc -l`"
    done
```

while reading documentation for gnu parallel

i found out that functions are not supported so getlinks wont be used in parallel

best i have found so far is

```
seq 30 | parallel -n 4 --colsep '  ' echo {1} {2} {3} {4}
```

makes output

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 
29 30
```

while loop mentioned above should go like this if I am right

```
end=`cat done1 |wc -l`
seq $end -1 1 |  parallel -j+4 -k
#(all exept getlinks function goes here, but idk how? )|
# everytime it finishes do
 getlinks $nextUrls
```

thx for help in advance

Comment: What do you actually want to do, and what is your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems what you want is a progress meter. Try:

```
cat done1 | parallel --eta wget
```

If that is not what you want, look at `sem` (`sem` is an alias for `parallel --semaphore` and is normally installed with GNU Parallel):

```
for i in `ls *.log` ; do
  echo $i
  sem -j+0 gzip $i ";" echo done
done
sem --wait
```

In your case it will be something like:

```
while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]
    do          
    percentage=${"scale=2;(100-(($n / $end) * 100))"|bc -l}}
    #get url from line specified by n from file done1
    nextUrls=`sed -n "${n}p" < done1`
    echo -ne "${percentage}%  $n / $end urls saved going to line 1. current: $nextUrls\r"
    #    function that gets links from the url
    THE_URL=`getlinks $nextUrls`
    sem -j10 wget $THE_URL
    #save n
    echo $n > currentLine
    let "n--"
    let "end=`cat done1 |wc -l`"
done
sem --wait
echo All done
```

Comment: thx but look at my next answer for what I am exactly looking for,

Answer (score 1):

Why does getlinks need to be a function?  Take the function and transform it into a shell script (should be essentially identical except you need to export environmental variables in and you of course cannot affect the outside environment without lots of work).

Of course, you cannot save $n into currentline when you are trying to execute in parallel.  All files will be overwriting each other at the same time.

Comment: i got this at the end of `getlinks sort -f done1 ">" done2
 uniq done2 ">" done1` if sorts and removes duplicate urls

Comment: only problem is makeing a parallel do this: percentage=${"scale=2;(100-(($n / $end) * 100))"|bc -l}}
    #get url from line specified by n from file done1              
nextUrls=`sed -n "${n}p" < done1`
    echo -ne "${percentage}%  $n / $end urls saved going to line 1. current: $nextUrls\r" and give $nextUrls after it finishes to getlinks

Comment: i do not care if when i read n its 20 or 30, given that i have 10 parallels at the same time, but problem would be if i had saved idk 10 and last line should be 5000

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking of makeing something more like this, if not parallel or sam something else because parallel does not supprot funcitons aka http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#aliases_and_functions_do_not_work

```
getlinks(){
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
    lynx -image_links -dump "$1" > src
    grep -i ".jpg" < src > links1
    grep -i "http"  < links1 >links  
    sed -e  's/.*\(http\)/http/g'  < links >> done1
    sort -f done1 > done2
    uniq done2 > done1
    rm -rf links1 links src done2 
fi
}
func(){
 percentage=${"scale=2;(100-(($1 / $end) * 100))"|bc -l}}
        #get url from line specified by n from file done1
        nextUrls=`sed -n "${$1}p" < done1`
        echo -ne "${percentage}%  $n / $end urls saved going to line 1. current: $nextUrls\r"
        #    function that gets links from the url
        getlinks $nextUrls
        #save n
        echo $1 > currentLine
        let "$1--"
        let "end=`cat done1 |wc -l`"
}
while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]
    do          
   sem -j10 func $n
done
sem --wait
echo All done
```

My script has become really complex, and i do not want to make a feature unavailable with something i am not sure it can be done
this way i can get links with full internet traffic been used, should take less time that way

Comment: If you make `func` and `getLinks` as into a script instead of a function then the above should work with minor modifications: You clearly have a race condition in getLinks, so you need to make sure the files you are saving are called something unique.

Answer (score 0):

tryed sem

```
#!/bin/bash
func (){
echo 1
echo 2
}


for i in `seq 10`
do
sem -j10 func 
done
sem --wait
echo All done
```

you get

errors

```
Can't exec "func": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.10/IPC/Open3.p
m line 168.
open3: exec of func  failed at /usr/local/bin/sem line 3168
```

Comment: god any way to do a function in a pipeline in bash

Comment: `sem` is an alias for `parallel --semaphore` and thus has the same restrictions on functions/aliases.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what the end goal of your script is. If you are trying to write a parallel web crawler, you might be able to use the below as a template.

```
#!/bin/bash

# E.g. http://gatt.org.yeslab.org/
URL=$1
# Stay inside the start dir
BASEURL=$(echo $URL | perl -pe 's:#.*::; s:(//.*/)[^/]*:$1:')
URLLIST=$(mktemp urllist.XXXX)
URLLIST2=$(mktemp urllist.XXXX)
SEEN=$(mktemp seen.XXXX)

# Spider to get the URLs
echo $URL >$URLLIST
cp $URLLIST $SEEN

while [ -s $URLLIST ] ; do
  cat $URLLIST |
    parallel lynx -listonly -image_links -dump {} \; wget -qm -l1 -Q1 {} \; echo Spidered: {} \>\&2 |
    perl -ne 's/#.*//; s/\s+\d+.\s(\S+)$/$1/ and do { $seen{$1}++ or print }' |
    grep -F $BASEURL |
    grep -v -x -F -f $SEEN | tee -a $SEEN > $URLLIST2
  mv $URLLIST2 $URLLIST
done

rm -f $URLLIST $URLLIST2 $SEEN
```